# User management: third party Identity Management vs local user

Tags: database-design, web-applications, identity

### Context

Let's considering a standard web application handling cars. Each car has an owner. So the car structure looks like:

```
cars(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  owner_id *???*
)
```

For simplicity reasons, I am using an external Identity Management, in my case [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). My question is **"how to represent users in a database when completely externalising Identity Management?"**. All user profile related information (such as personal information) are handled by the third party IDM.

#### Option 1: mapping of local users vs external users

A local `User` table is created:

```
users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- local user id
  external_id TEXT,       -- id in the third party IDM
)
```

Then, `Car` is mapped to the local user id:

```
cars(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  owner_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(id)
)
```

**Pros**

- Enforce data consistency: the car cannot be assigned to a non-existing user
- In case of a IDM change, only the `users` table needs to be remapped

**Cons**

- Back-end needs to catch the sign-up event to store the external id in its database
- After authentication, the external IDM needs to send the information *OK, external_id XXX is authenticated, his/her local ID is YYY*.
- the database/back-end needs to know when a new user is created
- Kind of duplicate the user ID information

#### Option 2: use external ID

`users` table is not created and `cars` ownership is defined by:

```
cars(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  owner_id TEXT NOT NULL -- the ID in the external IDM
)
```

Pros:

- Back-end is completely free from Identity management (new user, login, password forgotten...)
- after authentication, if using JWT, the ID provided by the external IDM can be used and there is no mapping to do

Cons:

- IDM-dependent. I notice that on Auth0, even social user ID depend on your tenant so if a new tenant is used or worst, IdaaS provider changes, a lot of remapping has to be done.
- Data integrity is not ensured for car ownership as there is no way to set a constraint at database level

### My understanding

I would go for option 1 because my OCD would ask for data integrity but does *option 2* exists somewhere down in this world?

Comment: Can a car change owners? Can an owner have many cars. Can a car have more than 1 owner at a time?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot, the answer is "yes" to all tour questions. The owner-car relationship is just an example and as you highlighted, I should mention that the question is extended to *any* kind of relationships

Answer (score 2):

There is no single correct answer. The right answer for you depends upon your requirement and how you chose to model the problem.

Depending upon the importance of the owner details they may be an entity in thier own right (requiring thier own table) or they could just be an attribute of car.

If you wish to capture/store any owner details beyond thier id, I would reccomend the first approach. If you wish to maintain owner details externally then go with the second.

Just because its odd or unconventional doesnt mean its wrong.

Comment: I have to say that specifically for Auth0, I take the limitation of request per second into account as I am using a free account. So my thoughts are not purely objective: In case of option 1, I need to submit a request to Auth0 whenever I want to know someone else information (name, nickname, email...) which is limited to [2 requests per second for free account](https://auth0.com/docs/policies/rate-limits#management-api-v2)

Comment: I think this is becoming more of a question of architechture than db schema design. Unless you have really compelling reason to keep the data in two different places i'd advise you keep it in the database. If you have limitations with your authentication and security design then you should address those.

Comment: I see. When you mentioned data, are you talking about user information (name, email and such) or just the `local ID <-> external provider ID` mapping? For my application specific users, I can indeed store everything in my database. I have a naive question: how about social user info? I could keep it in the database but nothing ensures that the data are up to date.

Comment: @Al-un You will need to store the mapping somewhere... keeping it in the database along with the user account it is associated with makes sense. The decision whether or not to replicate data is always difficult. keeping it syncronised and up to date is always a challenge. Personally I prefer to avoid duplication wherever possible. This problem is worthy of a whole question on it's own.

Comment: I do agree with this comment. Many thanks for sharing your thoughts !

Comment: I have got the same question. I was considering to use auth0 and my application has exact same requirement. It will have a heavy user searches etc. So I thought this approach to storing user data along with tokens in my own DB, which seems a big challenge when comes to syncing the data between auth0 and application